# MySQL: Update with select

Tags: mysql, joomla

I'm very new to SQL query statements.

My code is:

```
update #__comprofiler
set cb_fp_course_date =
[select #__eb_events.event_date from #__eb_events, #__eb_registrants
where #__eb_events.id = #__eb_registrants.event_id
and#__eb_registrants.user_id = '[user_id]'
and #__eb_events.alias = 'fp'
order by #__eb_events.event_date desc
limit 1]
where `user_id` = "[user_id]"
```

But it does not return a value when I check the table. Any help would be 
gratefully received.

Cheers,

-UPDATE-

Found this statement on mysql.com

In MySQL, you cannot modify a table and select from the same table in a subquery. This applies to statements such as DELETE, INSERT, REPLACE, UPDATE, and (because

Therefore I assume that a self join is required? Any ideas please?

Comment: this doesn't look like standard SQL, is this some kind of plugin? There seems to be a space missing in the line "and#__eb_registrants.user_id = '[user_id]'". Are you getting any error messages? Does the # hash indicate a variable substitution?

Comment: Hello Loopo,Yes,it's Community Builder plugin "Auto Actions", using the query function. The select statement works fine, it returns the date and time I am after, I now just need to save that daytime to a record in the comprofiler table so that I can refer to it again in the future.

Comment: I don't think you are updating (#__comprofiler) the same tables as you are selecting from (#__eb_events, #__eb_registrants).   I did notice that there is a weird quote in the last `where \`user_id\` = ‘[user_id]'`. this may be due to pasting it into a different editor before posting here though

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look at this for me, I'm going around in circles. I've changed the ' to " in the last line of code, but it has made no difference. There must be some way of updating a record in a table by carrying out a SELECT query?

Comment: Ultimately I just need to retrieve a date using the SELECT query in the above code, display it in a CB field then in a separate field display the date again but with a set number of months added on, for example 12, 24, 36 months, etc. But I am so confused that I now can't even work out where I am!!!!!!

Comment: I can help you but i need to check the plugin first. Can you upload that plugin here or can you just PM me the link.